# kubectl udp loadbalancer issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I'm having some issues with gcloud setting up a container and trying to use a loadbalancer

The problem is that I need it by udp and not tcp

I use this:

```
kubectl run mserver --image=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/mserver:v1 --port=28000
kubectl expose rc mserver --protocol=UDP --type="LoadBalancer"
```

using `--protocol=UDP` I receive this:

```
spec.ports[0].protocol: invalid value 'UDP', Details: cannot create an external load balancer with non-TCP ports
```

Any idea about if it's possible to create a load balancer by udp?

Answer (score 1):

This limitation is fixed in the next (v1.2) release of Kubernetes, for those clouds that support UDP load-balancing.

Comment: any idea when v1.2 will be available in gke?

Comment: It will be available in GKE with a week or two of the public launch of v1.2, which is soon.

Comment: Sounds great. how about its availability on google cloud container enviroment?

Comment: Once 1.2 is released it will be available on GCE by nature of it being open to download.  GKE does some qualification and will follow very shortly.  What else are you thinking?